# Como saber el numero que se repite mas veces dentro de una Array

Tags: javascript, array

Teniendo una Array, por ejemplo:

```
 var num= [1,1,2,2,2,2,3,1,1,1,3,3,3,3]
```

Me gustaría saber como obtener el numero que se repite mas veces.

¿Hay alguna función de `JS` que permita hacerlo?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué has investigado? Por favor, dale a [edit] y proporciona ejemplos, resultados deseados y, sobre todo, qué código has intentado.

Comment: Una idea de como hacerlo: Itera sobre el array de entrada y genera un array asociativo en que cada clave es el número encontrado, y como valor las veces que te encuentras ese número en el array. Para el ejemplo que has pasado te quedaría esto {"1":5, "2":4, "3":5}. Luego iteras por cada par clave-valor de este array asociativo y calculas el máximo. Te animo a que lo intentes tú, ya que tiene pinta de ser un ejercicio, intenta algo de código y si te atascas pégalo y vemos como lo podemos arreglar.

Comment: No existe una función nativa que haga exactamente eso, aún.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolverlo en pocas lineas y con un solo bucle se puede hacer de la siguiente forma:

```js
const masRepetido = (cad, cont={}, max=0, nums={}) => 
  cad.map(i => cont[i]==null ? cont[i]=1 : 
    ++cont[i] > max ? [max, nums[max]] = [cont[i], [i]] :
      cont[i] == max ? nums[max].push(i) : 0 ) 
    && `Se repiten ${max} veces : `+nums[max].join(',');


console.log(masRepetido([1,1,2,2,2,2,3,1,1,1,3,3,3,3]));
console.log(masRepetido([1,5,1,2,2,2,2,3,1,5,5,5,5,5,1,1,3,3,3,3]));
```

El anterior código muestra el elemento (o elementos) que mas se repite(n) y la cantidad de veces que aparece(n).

La lógica es preguntar si el número ya se esta contando. De no ser así se inicializa su contador en 1 y de otro modo se incrementa.

Luego se pregunta si es el contador es mayor al máximo, de ser así se actualiza dicho máximo y se guarda el numero, si no es mayor pero es igual, se guarda el numero junto al otro (o los otros) que aparecieron la misma cantidad de veces.

Espero sea lo que buscas, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La siguiente función te permitirá calcular cuáles son los números más repetidos, para el caso en el que se repitan igual número de veces los números la respuesta será un arreglo, si únicamente hay un número que se repite la mayor cantidad de veces la respuesta será un único número, espero que te ayude.

```js
function mostRepeatedNumbers(array) {
  let numberCount = {};

  array.forEach(number => {
    numberCount[number] = numberCount[number] + 1 || 1;
  });

  let sortedValues = Object.entries(numberCount)
    .sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1] == 0 ? parseInt(a[0]) - parseInt(b[0]): b[1] - a[1]);

  let baseValue = sortedValues[0][1];
  let result = [ parseInt(sortedValues[0][0]) ];

  for (let i = 1; i < sortedValues.length; i++) {
    if (sortedValues[i][1] == baseValue) {
      result.push(parseInt(sortedValues[i][0]));
    } else break;
  }

  return result.length > 1 ? result : result[0];
}

let arr = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3];

console.log(mostRepeatedNumbers(arr));
```